# What happens to exceptions raised in a with statement expression?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

My understanding of Python's `with` statement is as follows:

`with` statement = `with` + *expression* + `as` + *target* + `:` + *suit*

1. *expression* is executed and returns a context manager
2. context manager's `__enter__` returns a value to *target*
3. The *suite* is executed.
4. context manager's `__exit__` method is invoked

I know exceptions can be handled in step2 and step3, my question is that if an exception is thrown during the step1 when *expression* is executed, can I get a context manager?

If not does that mean that the `with` statement just ensures the *suit* to be executed and close properly?

Like `with open("file") as f`,  if the file does not exist what will happen?

Comment: You already figured it out; if *expression* raises an exception there can be no context manager, so no, the `with` statement cannot handle that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `with` statement only manages exceptions in *step 3*. If an exception is  raised in step 1 (executing *expression*) or in step 2 (executing the context manager `__enter__` method), you *do not have a (valid and working) context manager* to hand the exception to.

So if the file does not exist, an exception is raised in step 1 and cannot be handled by a context manager, because that context manager was never created.

If that is a problem, you can always execute the *expression* part separately:

```
try:
    context_manager = expression
except SomeSpecificException:
    # do something about the exception
else:
    with context_manager as target:
        # execute the suite
```

If the exception is raised in `__enter__` (step 2) the context hasn’t yet been entered and so `__exit__` will not be called. Your only option to handle an exception at that step is to put the whole `with` statement inside a `try...except` block.